# Understanding something about the definition of a topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

My lecturer told us that the elements of a topology $\mathcal{J}$ on $X$ are called open sets. He also prove the statement "every metric space is a topological space". Since I wasn't able to ask him about the open sets, I want to ask here:

i) Are the elements of $\mathcal{J}$ really open sets, or are they just defined to be open sets? (Note that I know the definition of an open set).

ii) In the book of Munkres, it says that if $U\in \mathcal{J}$ then $U$ is an open set, where $U\subseteq X$. Does the converse implication also hold, the way I understood in the abovementioned statement?

Comment: What is your definition of an open set?

Comment: @Bungo A subset $A$ of $X$ is open if and only if for all $x\in A$ there exists a radius $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subseteq A$.

Comment: Different topologies are possible on the same set.  They will give different open sets.  Yes the elements of a topology  $\mathcal{J}$ are called open by definition.

Comment: @AjmalW That definition of an open set only applies to a metric space. The topology on a set of which your instructor speaks and of which Munkres defines is an abstraction of those kind of sets.

Comment: @AjmalW that's for topologies induced by metrics. But for general topologies, we may not have a metric or a norm. For instance, if $X$ is any non-empty set and $\mathcal T = \mathcal P(X)$, the power set of $X$, then $\mathcal T$ is a topology on $X$ and a set is open if and only if it's an element of $\mathcal P(X)$; there are no balls and stuff involved.

Comment: @AhmedHussein Well, the discrete metric works here. A better example is the co-finite or the indiscrete topology, e.g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$U \in \mathcal{T}$ and "$U$ is open" are synonyms. One implies the other.

Also, it's more correct to say "a metric space has a (standard) topology associated with it". Having a metric $d$ on a set $X$, we *define* a topology $\mathcal{T}_d$ on $X$ as those sets $U$ such that $\forall x \in U: \exists r>0: B(x,r) \subseteq U$, and then one checks the axioms for a topology. The $d$ actually gives more structure in many ways, but having a topology allows you to discuss topological notions and apply theorems from general topology. But metric spaces yield very special topologies (as you might see later on).

Answer (score 1):

The Topology of some Topological space $X$ is (usually) defined the be the collection of open subsets of $X$. So, by definition of $\mathcal{T}_X$, the Topology of $X$, we know that any $Y\in \mathcal{T}_X$ must be an open set.